# Node JS: how to get access to ES6 class from another file?

Tags: javascript, commonjs, referenceerror

Good day. I have 3 different files: app.js, task.js, index.html.

task.js - model of the task. It contains:

```
module.exports = class Task {
    constructor(author, header, priority, description, id) {
        //...
    }

    //...
};
```

app.js contains:

```
const Task = require("./js/models/Task");
```

I can create an instance of the task in app.js:

```
const task = new Task();
```

But when i try to attach task.js to index.html:

`<script src="../js/models/Task.js" type="text/javascript"></script>`

and run the server, i get an error:

```
ReferenceError: module is not defined   
module.exports = class Task
```

How i can create an instance of the Task?

Comment: Why is this tagged with Node.js?

Answer (score 3):

The [CommonJS](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/modules.html) module syntax is only supported natively by Node. It's not supported natively by the browser. You can use [Browserify](http://browserify.org/) to bundle up CommonJS modules to a format your browser understands, should you want the syntax to work on the browser.